# Cloudflare 522 Connection Timed Out

Tags: apache2, cloudflare

I'm not sure what's going on, but this all happened when I changed from one VPS provider to the next.

I have multiple websites, all connected through Cloudflare, all pointing to the same VPS, and Apache2 setup.

I've got https://level42.ca, and https://lumpysoft.com

level42.ca, works perfectly fine, both at http and https, while lumpysoft.com provides me a 522 when I try to connect. I've compared the sites-enabled.conf files of both sites, and configuration wise, they're pretty much identical.

The odd thing though, is that if I visit lumpysoft.com via a sub-domain (also pointed to the same IP), then it works and lets me through.

A lot of the reading I've done suggests that there's either a firewall issue (which I doubt as level42.ca works) or a server configuration error, which, if so, I cannot find.

Below are my two .conf files, perhaps someone can see something that I don't ...

level42.ca

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin level42@domain.ca
        ServerName level42.ca
        ServerAlias www.level42.ca
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/level42.ca/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/html/level42.ca/public_html>
#               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
#               Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

#       LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

lumpysoft.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin level42@domain.ca
        ServerName lumpysoft.com
        # ServerAlias cannot be the same as ServerName
        ServerAlias www.lumpysoft.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lumpysoft.com/public_html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

EDIT, here is my firewall configuration on my Ubuntu Server:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp (Postfix)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY IN     115.249.75.237
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (Postfix (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

DNS:

lumpysoft.com: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQb3m.jpg

level42.ca: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMYab.jpg

Comment: Check your CloudFlare DNS settings.

Comment: From what I can tell, they more or less match that of website1.ca I can't see any noticeable differences.

Comment: None of us can tell, as there isn't anything shown here.

Comment: ... so, what needs to be shown? I mean, my .conf files are far from nothing ...

Comment: I've appended my Firewall configuration, in case that helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual domain names so we can check DNS.

Comment: ... fixed .....

Comment: How about the CloudFlare DNS settings?

Comment: Added DNS ..... Anything else I can provide?